# How to integrate $\int_0^{2}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[6]{x+2}}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Are there some tips about how to integrate a function that has a sum of radicals in the denominator?

$$\int_0^{2}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[6]{x+2}}\,dx$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**

Taking $x+2=t^6$, you get a rational integrand:
$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[6]{x+2}}\,\mbox{d}x=\int \frac{6t^5}{1+t+t^2+t^3}\,\,\mbox{d}t$$

Comment: Afterwards you can use a partial fraction decompostion.

Comment: Indeed; note that $1+t+t^2+t^3=(1+t)(1+t^2)$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try, stupidly, that substitution

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $$x+2=t^6$$ then $$x=t^6-2$$ and $$dx=6t^5dt$$